# Pip: "Skipping (some_package) as it is not installed"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab as a virtual environment and have the following code:

```
!pip3 install turicreate
!pip3 uninstall -y mxnet
!pip3 install mxnet-cu100==1.4.0.post0
!pip3 install coremltools
!pip3 install onnxmltools
```

The output results this:

```
WARNING: Skipping mxnet as it is not installed.
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning printed by `!pip3 uninstall -y mxnet` because you are trying to uninstall a module who isn't already installed, here `mxnet`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pip list`, then find the actual name of package 'mxnet', then uninstall it.