# Uninstall Spyder on Ubuntu

Tags: python, spyder

I have installed Spyder 6.0.0a3 on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
Now I want to uninstall 6.0.0a3 to older version.

I tried `pip uninstall spyder` but it produces `WARNING: Skipping spyder as it is not installed.`

To initiate Spyder, I just type `spyder` on my terminal.

Can someone help me with uninstallation of Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 uninstall spyder` it remove spyder on python3

Comment: same `WARNING: Skipping spyder as it is not installed.`

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923972/pip-skipping-some-package-as-it-is-not-installed

Comment: I could not find spyder in `pip list`

Answer (score 0):

First, check if SPYDER was installed via apt

```
dpkg -l | grep spyder
```

if you see the package, note it's name and uninstall

```
sudo apt remove <package_name>
```

Comment: there is no output to `dpkg -l | grep spyder`

Comment: Run snap list and flatpak list to see if Spyder was installed through Snap or Flatpak.  or remove it manually